# App preview doesn't show up

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I added git to the project as well as the git ignore file for [android projects](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore).

Now I cannot see the preview of my app [image: image from android studio] It also in the `logcat` prompts me to configure Android SDK. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean Project or Rebuild Project or Restart Android Studio.